# django: query objects with hour in certain range

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-queryset

I want to select all objects in my database within a certain range of hours (say 9 to 12). Right now, i'm doing it this way:

```
my_range = range(9,12)
excluded_range = [x for x in range(24) if not x in my_range]

selected_objects = MyModel.objects.all()
for hour in excluded_range:
    selected_objects = selected_objects.exclude(datetimefield__hour=hour)
```

Is there a way to this using queries only? (using django 1.7)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
Your method will hit the database for every iteration in the for loop.
Consider using the following

```
from django.db.models import Q

queries = [Q(datetimefield__hour=hour) for hour in range(9, 12)]
query = queries.pop()

for _query in queries:
    query |= _query
selected_objects = MyModel.objects.filter(query)
```

Comment: gte, lte, and in are not supported on datetime__hour, datetime__minute fields

Comment: True that. Updated the answer, please check.

Comment: Actually, reading again the django docs, my method does not hit the database multiple times - not even once really. Check out [this documentation page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated). If there was a way to `or` all elements in `query` with an one-liner, this way would make more sense, at least because of it's readability.

Comment: A year later: the one liner I was looking for is [reduce](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the following one-liner using [reduce](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
my_range = range(9, 12)

query = reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, Q(field__hour=h) for h in my_range)

selected_objects = Model.objects.filter(query)
```